# Changing syntax token with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to rewrite code with Roslyn.
I want to change GreaterThanToken to EqualsEqualsToken. Here is my code so far:

ToParse.cs:

```
public class ToParse
{
    public bool MethodToConvert(int param)
    {
        return (1 > param);
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
class Rewriter : SyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly SyntaxKind _replace;
    private readonly SyntaxKind _replacewith;
    public Rewriter(SyntaxKind replace, SyntaxKind replacewith)
    {
        _replace = replace;
        _replacewith = replacewith;
    }

    public override SyntaxToken VisitToken(SyntaxToken token)
    {
        if (token.Kind != _replace)
            return token;

        return Syntax.Token(_replacewith);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var code = new StreamReader("ToParse.cs").ReadToEnd();
var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
var root = tree.GetRoot();
var rewriter = new Rewriter(SyntaxKind.GreaterThanToken, SyntaxKind.EqualsEqualsToken);
var newRoot = rewriter.Visit(root);

var newTree = SyntaxTree.Create((CompilationUnitSyntax)newRoot);
var compilation = Compilation.Create("TestAssembly.dll", 
      new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
      references: new[]{ new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)},
      syntaxTrees: new[] { newTree });
Console.WriteLine(newTree);
EmitResult res;

using (var file = new FileStream("e:\\TestAssembly.dll", FileMode.Create))
   res = compilation.Emit(file);
```

After execution, Console.WriteLine prints changed tokens `return (1 == param);`
But when I open testassembly.dll with ilspy I still see `return 1 > param;`
Any suggestions?

Comment: did you rebuild the project?

Comment: Yes.I also tried Debug/release configuration

Comment: Roslyn does not allow you to rewrite during compilation.

Comment: But he should be able to rewrite before compilation, which I believe is the case here.

Answer (score 6):

[Note: You're using a slightly older version of Roslyn. This answer should work for that version too, but I may reference classes and members by more recent names so that they match the source available on [CodePlex](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/).]

The original tree that you've parsed contains a `BinaryExpressionSyntax` node with a `SyntaxKind` of [`GreaterThanExpression`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxKind.cs#ace2836b7d369e2d). When you swap out the `GreaterThanToken` with an `EqualsEqualsToken`
inside this `BinaryExpressionSyntax`, it does **not** automatically adjust the containing `SyntaxNode`'s *kind* to `EqualsExpression`.

As a result, you end up with a `GreaterThanExpression` with an `EqualsEqualsToken`. Since this is not a syntax tree that could have been legally generated by the compiler itself, you may see unexpected behavior like this.

To generate a correct tree in this case, I'd recommend rewriting the node itself instead of the token by overriding [`CSharpSyntaxRewriter.VisitBinaryExpression`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/obj/Debug/Syntax.xml.Generated.cs#336e09dcabe4a0e5) and doing something like this:

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpressionSyntax node)
{
    if (node.CSharpKind() == SyntaxKind.GreaterThanExpression)
    {
        return SyntaxFactory.BinaryExpression(SyntaxKind.EqualsExpression, node.Left, node.Right);
    }

    return node;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't some part the compilation process verify that the syntax tree doesn't contain this kind of errors?